# How can I get the index of the current slide, when the slide is changed?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I have the following

```
mySwiper = new Swiper('.my-swiper', {
    direction: 'vertical',
    loop: true,
});
mySwiper.on('slideChange', function () {
    console.log('*** mySwiper.realIndex', mySwiper.realIndex);
});
```

But `realIndex` always returns the previous index. So if I'm on the first slide (0) and go to the next, `realIndex` is 0 when it should be 1. When I go back to the first slide `realIndex` is 1 when it should be 0. So it seems the event fires before the index is updated. I've tried other events but haven't had any luck. Is there an event that fires *after* the slide is changed so that I can capture the current slide index?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Swiper, but is there possibly an event object passed to the `slideChange` listener that would tell you what you want, like `mySwiper.on('slideChange', function (event) {...`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use `transitionEnd` event as Event will be fired after the transition.

see a demo below

```js
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  direction: 'vertical',
  loop: true,
});
mySwiper.on('transitionEnd', function() {
  console.log('*** mySwiper.realIndex', mySwiper.realIndex);
});
```

```css
.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  z-index: 999999 !important;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.2.6/css/swiper.min.css">
<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Swiper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.2.6/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
```

***Note: If you are not able to see the `console.log` statement output in the snippet, use `F12` to see the index of the slide.***

Answer (score 5):

```
mySwiper.on('slideChange', function (e) {
    console.log('*** mySwiper.activeIndex', mySwiper.activeIndex);
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 2):

You can Access all property and methods available by swiper  in your callback function.

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {      
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    }
});

swiper.on('slideChange', function () {
    myCallbackfunction(this);

  });

function myCallbackfunction(data){
    console.log(data.realIndex);
    //console.log(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the API, there's an event `slideChangeTransitionEnd` which "...will be fired after animation to other slide (next or previous)". That sounds like a promising event to try instead of `slideChange`.

http://idangero.us/swiper/api/

Answer (score 1):

If you use new versions of swiper js, you should use "on" keyword inside of Swiper "options" param, see below code for example

```
Swiper(".swiper-post",  { 
    on: { 
        slideChange: function() {
          let slideCurrentIndex = this.realIndex; // get current slide's index
          console.log(this.realIndex); write it to console
    }}
})
```